SQL query to group by if column value exists, else list all records
I have some reports in a SQL database. Some reports have a report number, some reports don't have a report number.



Report_id
Report_created_by
Versions
Report_number




1
John Smith
1
101


2
John Smith
2
101


3
Jack Johson




4
Madeline Joe





I would like to group reports that have a report number, and list all reports that don't have a report number.
So I should get a result like this:



Report_id
Report_created_by
Versions
Report_number




1
John Smith
1
101


3
Jack Johson




4
Madeline Joe





How should I write my SQL query?
Note: I am already using a UNION to solve this but am looking for a better solution.
Thank you.

How do you chose which row(s) to keep for the reports with numbers? Or rather what do you mean by group? I suspect you don't have enough sample data to illustrate properly.

What options have you researched, considered, tried?

I would like to select rows with minimum version, and group by Report_number.

Let's say the Report with id 2 has been created by Max Joe and not John Smith, what does this mean for your result?

Please update your question with that detail and add sample data to support

I suggest a query for each of your 2 scenarios and union them together

If report  with id 2 has been created by Max Joe, then it will either have a unique report id (102) or no id at all (currently application will generate id)

Thanks Dale K. I am currently using union, but wondering if possible to have 1 query without union.

Why? What do you hope to gain by removing the union? (Another detail you should add to your question)

The "empty" values here, are they represented as NULL values in the DB?

yes, empty values are NULLs

UNIONs means my script will run twice. if possible, I would like to run query just once - and hopefully improve performance.

If you wish to improve performance then that is a completely different question and you should state that in your question, and you must provide an execution plan for performance related questions. ( using Paste The Plan)

@qed59 Do I understand correct that you want this query? https://dbfiddle.uk/v29DKIZW Since the two queries fetches different rows (the first those with report number, the second those without), the performance will be fine.

Hi @JonasMetzler, yes, this is what I have at the moment. So there's no other way to write this query except using UNION?

@qed59 Then I think you should keep this and doubt other queries would be faster.

@qed59, maybe dense_rank() would be an alternative? https://dbfiddle.uk/xYNgHJV1

@Andrei Odegov: That is a very good idea. Makes the query very short, readable and thus maintainable. It must be guaranteed that reports without a report number have no report version, of course.

@qed59: I just stumbled upon a comment above ... If this is a table and one report_number must always be assigned the same creator, then you have a problem in your database, because you are violating database normalization. It would have one table for the report header then, to show who created the report, and one table for the report versions.

@Andrei Odegov: I think you should make this an answer.

@charlieface your dup doesn't answer the question, OP wants all rows for the null group - not just the top one

Damn didn't realise I could single handedly reopen it. I see why you flagged it now, because the answer is the dup, but really the answer doesn't match the question description.

You can get the row number after sorting the versions for every report_created_by using row_number() over (), then select the first record:
with lowest_report_versions as (
  select 
    reports.*, 
    row_number() over (partition by report_created_by order by versions) as r
   from reports
)
select * 
from lowest_report_versions 
where r = 1 
order by report_id

db<>fiddle

And why do you think this is "better" than using UNION ALL? I tried both in my DB and UNION ALL was executed slightly faster (might depend on indices). See this answer

This will not work, if a person creates more than one report, because the OP wants the first version for each report number, which unfortunately is no crystal clear from the request, but they clarify this in the request comments.

@JonasMetzler I don't think it's better per se, but OP asked for alternatives to UNION

@VvdL They asked am looking for a better solution, not I want to know all other solutions, so I think an answer that proposes another solution should explain its advantage.


Note: I am already using a UNION to solve this but am looking for a better solution.

UNION is the best solution.
with
  null_report as
  (
    select report_id, report_created_by, versions, report_number
    from reports
    where report_number is null
  ),
  first_non_null_report as
  (
    select top(1) with ties
      report_id, report_created_by, versions, report_number
    from reports report_number
    where report_number is not null
    order by row_number() over (partition by report_number order by versions)
  )
select * from null_report
union all
select * from first_non_null_report
order by report_id;

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/Y5qLaJA5

I think UNION is the best solution should be replaced with UNION ALL is the best solution as often people confuse UNION with UNION ALL , especially in terms of performance

Maybe dense_rank() would be an alternative?
select *
from ( select top(1) with ties
         report_id, report_created_by, versions, report_number
       from reports report_number
       order by dense_rank() over(partition by report_number
                                  order by versions) ) first_reports
order by report_id;

db<>fiddle
